# Passing extra variable with Django ListView

Tags: django, variables

Can't pass extra variable with listview

I tried adding another function and returning the value but it then doesn't return the main part.

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        posting = []
        for post in Post.objects.all():
            post_words = post.content.split()
            for word in post_words:
                posting.append(word.lower())

        mostused_word = []
        for word in posting:
            if len(mostused_word) == 0:
                mostused_word.append({'daword': word, 'word_count': posting.count(word)})
            else:
                if posting.count(word) > mostused_word[0]['word_count']:
                    mostused_word[0] = {'daword': word, 'word_count': posting.count(word)}
        context = {
            'mostused_word': mostused_word[0]['daword'],
            'mostused_word_count': mostused_word[0]['word_count'],
            'postin': posting,
            }
        return context
```

I expect to pass both needed variables, not only one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the super method.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    context = {
        'mostused_word': mostused_word[0]['daword'],
        'mostused_word_count': mostused_word[0]['word_count'],
        'postin': posting,
    }
    kwargs.update(context)
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: You don't know how much you are helping with this, been trying to find the answer for so long, thank you!